# Problem with playing audio with alsa

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I am using `alsa` with `pulse audio-1.0.25` and I am using ATI Radeon E4690 graphics card with standard Fedora-17 OS.

When I am trying to play audio with alsa, its not playing anything and coming out quickly.

I am passing `radeon.audio=1` as boot argument.

But my card is getting detected when I am giving the commands as below.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

aplay -L
null
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
PulseAudio Sound Server
default
Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
HDMI Audio Output
```

But when I am playing the music its showing like

```
aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

It is looking like playing but its coming out very quickly and nothing is audible.